# Error 4058 on mkdir

Tags: node.js, fs

I am planning to save my resized image to a directory that is not yet created. This is my first time doing file manipulation on nodejs, and for some reason I am having this error. Am I missing something?

[image]

Code Here:
http://pastebin.com/LxRqciXN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to create a folder inside one non existing folder through `fs.mkdir`. This `error 4058` could come up. This problem can be solved by [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) module

```
var fs = require('fs-extra')

fs.mkdirs('/tmp/some/long/path/that/prob/doesnt/exist', function (err) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)
  console.log("success!")
})
```

Comment: I actually solved this by using mkdir and loop to my intended directory. But this one made it better. Thanks!!!